# unable to locate elements using uiautomator in android native app

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Using Appium for automating Android Native app.
I am identifying elements using android UIAutomator
Issue : I have eleven android `textview` fields which changes daily.
I am unable to read their values as all the eleven fields have same `classname` and same `resource -id`.
Then i tried using `Xpath` but what i saw was when i navigate to the textView all the textviews have same index value resulting in all 11 textviews have same `Xpath`.

I am using this code:

```
List<WebElement> dailychanged=driver.findElementsById("resource-id of your elements");
for (int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){
    System.out.println(dailychanged.get(i).getText());
}
```

Now I am unable to identify elements. Kindly suggest.

Comment: can you please share the snapshot of the UIautomator

Comment: i am using this code : List<WebElement> dailychanged=driver.findElementsById("resource-id of your elements");
for (int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){
    System.out.println(dailychanged.get(i).getText())
}   but  my code is able to read only first five elements next five elements need scrolling in order to be displayed on screen.. so now the real question is how can i read all the list view elements of android even if they need scrolling to be visible on screen

Comment: Add list.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.UP, 400) into loop

Answer (score 2):

Try using `@index` attribute to refer necessary one. For example:
`//android.widget.EditText[@index=0]`.

To write your xpath:

- a. Start with the class //class
- b. Add attributes [@attribute=”attribute_value”]
- E.g.: XPath to identify the text 8 in 
  the calculator app is `“//android.widget.EditText[@index=0]”`. We
  can    use ‘text’, ‘content description’ and other attribute to write
  xpath.

Please, see full article [here](http://seleniumcucumber.info/2015/02/02/locating-elements-of-android-application/).